# simplesamlphp "some" blank pages

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I installed simplesamlphp to set up SSO configuration towards an ADFS server. But I have issues when I am trying to convert their metadata.

I can successfully log in to the initial installation welcome page, as well as other links such as authentication and federation tab, test the configuration etc.

But I get blank pages, when I click the "Configuration" tab, "Show Metadata" in Federation tab, or when I go to metadata converter page and click on "Parse". Basically I am guessing there is a redirection error, somewhere in the configuration code, but I couldn't find it in the internet.

I see below errors in the logs.

```
Jun 12 13:25:47 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Error 1 - Call to undefined function curl_init()
Jun 12 13:25:47 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] Backtrace:
Jun 12 13:25:47 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 2 /var/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:86 (SimpleSAML_error_handler)
Jun 12 13:25:47 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 1 /var/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:54 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
Jun 12 13:25:47 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 0 [builtin] (N/A)


Jun 12 13:26:00 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[1478]: 3 [e14c321c1d] SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Error 1 - Class 'DOMDocument' not found
Jun 12 13:26:00 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[1478]: 3 [e14c321c1d] Backtrace:
Jun 12 13:26:00 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[1478]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 2 /var/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:86 (SimpleSAML_error_handler)
Jun 12 13:26:00 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[1478]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 1 /var/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:54 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
Jun 12 13:26:00 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[1478]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 0 [builtin] (N/A)


Jun 12 13:26:22 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Error 1 - Class 'DOMDocument' not found
Jun 12 13:26:22 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] Backtrace:
Jun 12 13:26:22 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 2 /var/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:86 (SimpleSAML_error_handler)
Jun 12 13:26:22 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 1 /var/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:54 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
Jun 12 13:26:22 ip-10-8-17-72 simplesamlphp[27328]: 3 [e14c321c1d] 0 [builtin] (N/A)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution.

The reason was the missing modules for php.

After running below commands, everyting works.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```